# When open mapping theorem fails.

Tags: operator-theory

Let *Y* = $L^1 $($\mu$) where $\mu$ is counting measure on **N**.

Let *X* = {$f$ $\in$ *Y* : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ *n*|$f(n)$|

Define *T* : *X* -> *Y*   by   $Tf(n)=nf(n)$

Now Let $S=T$$^{-1}$

Show $S$ is not open.

---

I think $S$ cannot be open since *X* is not complete.

So I guess that's why Open mapping theorem doesn't work here.

But I don't know know how to find an example to show that S is not open.

I don't even know how 'open sets' look like in *Y*

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is bijective and continuous, so if $S$ is also open, it's a homeomorphism from $Y$ to $X$. Let $f_i\in X$ denotes the function which sends $j\in\mathbb N$ to $1$ if $j=i$ and $0$ if $j\neq i$. Note that $S$ sends the non-convergent sequence $\{\sqrt nf_n\}$ to convergent sequence $\{\frac 1{\sqrt n}f_n\}$, so it cannot be a homeomorphism.